# set user status offline when someone colse browser or leave my website in php and javascript

Tags: javascript, offline, status

how we can set a user's status offline in usermaster.is_online to 0 in database when he leave my website or close browser tab or browser window, But not when he refresh the page or click on a link..

Comment: Dot forget to marks answer as accpeted if you got the info you want ...

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to check if visitor's IP Address is still active or online?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9450736/how-to-check-if-visitors-ip-address-is-still-active-or-online)

Comment: The link above by Joseph is probably the option I would use.

Answer (score 0):

I checkout some functions at php manual for handling client status like connection_aborted and connection_status, You can verify same with the following link if they can help you
 http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.connection-aborted.php